# Employement rate and labour force growth rate

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics

In an economy where the employment growth rate is greater than the labour force growth rate,
• the number of unemployed people decreases.

ANSWER: (i don't understand from where he takes those percentages)

**Undecidable**. Assume that: N^a = Labour force; L = employment; U= Unemployment
Then, N^a = L + U
Then, U = N^a – L
Now, we can use two numeric examples of growth rates for N^a and L
Assume that N^a = L + U is equal to 100=80+20
In case 1, the growth rate of L is larger: 100 (1+5%)=80(1+10%) + U
Then, U = 105-88 = 17; U decreases
In case 2, the growth rate of L is also larger: 100 (1+19%)=80(1+20%) + U
Then, U = 119-96 = 23; U increases

Comment: What is your question?